# Sort a gridview without call database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to sort a gridview without call the database. The goal is to stay on the same page and sort datas with buttons up/down at the right of the gridview ( in two templatefields) and to do only one call to the database a the end (submit button) . It will be and update with stored procedure.
It is possible to do that with the Gridview's properties ? Someone say to me to use a datatable to sort, but i can't transfer gridwiew's data to a table it don't work, i've ever try with differents ways. i think to an other solution, it's to put gridview's data in a XML file and modify it with XSLT. What's yours ideas to implement that ?

Cordialy

Julien

Comment: Welcome to SO Julien, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: There are client-side Javascripts that could do this for you if you don't want to do a postback. It'll be a little tricky getting the gridview table ID, but other than that it should be possible. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/03/33-javascript-solutions-for-sorting-tables/

Comment: @Julien698 - You can grab data into DataTable and store in session. To sort, get DataTable from Session, sort it, bind to GridView and store back in Session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.enablesortingandpagingcallbacks(v=vs.110).aspx
you cannot handle client-side sorting or paging if you are using template fields.
You would be better off not using an asp.net server control. 
If you own or can purchase Kendo UI, or if the free GPLv3 license is appropriate for your project, you can use the Kendo UI grid. It provides easy client-side sorting filtering and paging.
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html

Of course, googling will turn up many other vendors with similar offerings.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly i got the solution. I pass Gridview's datas to a DataTable, then I rebind Gridview with the DataTable. The Datas are temporary stocked with this manner. Then i compare the first DataTable with the last, and take only the modified lines to submit to server. It's work good !
Thanks for you anwser !